# Can't initialise GIT SCM on Mac OS High Sierra

Tags: django, git

I am a complete novice in programming. Please don't make fun of me. I am trying to learn programming in Django. I wish to use GIT SCM to manage version control of my project. I seem to have succeeded in installing GIT SCM but I am not being able to initialise it and move forward. Could someone please help me ?

Below you can find the error message thrown at me by the terminal. 
MacBook Pro (13 inch, early 2011) 
MacOS High Sierra (version 10.13.3)

> $ git init
>   xcrun: error: active developer path ("/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer") does not exist
>   Use `sudo xcode-select --switch path/to/Xcode.app` to specify the Xcode that you wish to use for command line developer tools, or use `xcode-select --install` to install the standalone command line developer tools.
>   See `man xcode-select` for more details.`

Comment: Have you tried running `xcode-select - - install`?

Comment: Yes, I did. It didn't rectify the problem.